# Add to an array in a function in PowerShell is not working like I thought

Tags: powershell

When I add to an array in a function, it works in the [ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/windows-powershell-integrated-scripting-environment--ise-), but in the command window it does not add.

```
Clear
$array = @()

FUNCTION AddtoArray() {
    Write "start of function"
    $array
    $global:array += "c "
    Write "result of add to array function"
    $array
}

$array = "a "
Write "New array"
$array
$array += "b "
Write "Add to array"
$array
AddtoArray
Write "Back from Function"
$array
```

When I run this in PowerGUI or PowerShell ISE I get:

a

a b

a b

a b c

a b c

When I run this from the Powershell command windows I get:

a

a b

a b

a b

a b

The function += is not adding the "c" when the script is called from the PS cmd window. When I ran it without $global:array += "c " it would work in PowerGui but PS ISE would return just the addition and lose the "a b".

Comment: What version of PowerShell?  I see the ISE results in V2 and V4 consoles.

Comment: V3 and V4, yes, ISE is running as expected, it's when it is ran from the PS cmd window that the issue shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Global` scope represents the topmost scope of any session, and when you open a prompt and assign `$a = "123"`, then you're implicitly writing to `$Global:a`.

But when you launch a script, such as:

```
PS C:\> # Inside our global scope here at the prompt we just opened
PS C:\> .\TestAddToArray.ps1
a 
a b
a b
a b
a b
PS C:\>
```

Any variable assignment inside the `TestAddToArray.ps1` file defaults to a `Script` scope - one that's shared among all the variables and functions inside that script file, but still a child scope to `Global`.

So, when you first initialize `$array`, you believe `$array` to mean `$Global:array`, but depending on the execution context, it might actually mean `$Script:array` (skipped the duplicate output):

```
PS C:\> # Inside our global scope here at the prompt we just opened
PS C:\> .\TestAddToArray.ps1
a   # $Script:array is now "a" - $Global:array doesn't exist
a b # $Script:array is now "a ","b " - $Global:array doesn't exist
a b # $Script:array is still "a ","b " - $Global:array is now "c "
PS C:\>
```

As an experiment, try and call the script 4-5 times, and then type `$Global:array` and see how many `"c "`s have been added

The dynamic scope model used in PowerShell can be a little confusing, but it's pretty well explained in the help files:

```
Get-Help about_Scopes -Full | more
```

As the help file mentions, you can reference ancestor scopes by supplying an [int] as the `-Scope` parameter argument (where `0` represents the local/current scope, 1 is the direct parent scope etc.), and herein lies a powerful "workaround":

```
function AddToArray {
    $temp = (Get-Variable -Name array -Scope 1).Value
    $temp += "c "
    Set-Variable -Name array -Scope 1 -Value $temp
}
```

Now, if `AddToArray` is defined and called from the Global scope, it'll write back to $Global:array (the immediate parent scope), but if it happens inside a script file, it now writes back to `$Script:array` since the `Script` scope is the immediate parent scope in this context.

The script then becomes:

```
clear
$array = @()

function AddtoArray {
    Write "start of function"
    $array
    $temp = (Get-Variable -Name array -Scope 1).Value
    $temp += "c "
    Set-Variable -Name array -Scope 1 -Value $temp
    Write "result of add to array function"
    $array
}

$array = "a "
Write "New array"        
$array
$array += "b "        
Write "Add to array"
$array
AddtoArray
Write "Back from Function"
$array
```

And you'll find that the output is consistent no matter if it's pasted into the command line, executed from a nested prompt, a separate script file, the editor in ISE (you get the idea)

Comment: Excellent answer! [about_Scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) is also available online, which you can also get to with `Get-Help about_Scopes -Online`.

Comment: Thank you Mathias, that makes sense, and I do have multiple "c" as you explained. What is the correct formatting then to have the array added to instead of replaced?

Comment: @Michael Oh, this was in a script file.  You should have mentioned that in your post.  I just figured you were F5'ing in ISE and pasting into the console.  To fix, change `$global:array` in your function to `$script:array`.

Comment: @Michael updated answer with a solution (ab)using the relativity between child/parent scopes

Comment: Sorry Keith, I wasn't sure the proper name for it so i was just calling it Powershell Command Window, I meant the non ISE run space. 

Changing to $Script:array worked! Thank you, I can't mark this as the correct answer for you to get the points from the comments section. Can you repost as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Just to add on to the answers, both Mathias and Keith gave good answers that worked for me.

Mathias created a new var $temp with the value from $array and then added to it with +=; then set the value of $temp back to $array with the Set-Var cmdlet.

Keith did a $script:array += "c "; which seemed to work as well and saved 2 lines. I'm not sure which way is more correct but they both worked.